# Luminosity Schechter function for galaxies

Tags: galaxy, luminosity

Just a question I am having trouble understanding. I have the Schechter luminosity function for galaxies, given as:

$$\Phi(L)dL=\Phi_{0}\left({\frac{L}{L_{\star}}}\right)^{\alpha}e^{-\frac{L}{L_{\star}}}\frac{dL}{L_{\star}}$$

I need to consider the case when $\alpha=-1$. And then show that the average luminosity of a galaxy is exactly $L_{\star}$. Could somebody explain how I could go about doing this and perhaps a hint or some part of a setup would be excellent. I really need to understand this.

Another part, which is related to the above question, is asking me to explain why the total luminosity is a finite number, whereas the total number of galaxies diverges. By this does it mean that the total number is infinite? Any extra comments on this would also be really appreciated.

Comment: The second part of this is easy enough, it just involves a couple of integrals, the first converges (for the total luminosity per unit volume) to $\Phi_0 L^*$ and the second diverges at the low luminosity limit (for the total number of galaxies per unit volume). My problem is that this implies that the average luminosity of a galaxy is zero. Only if we take $\Phi_0$ as some sort of "typical" space number density for galaxies do we have that $L^*$ is the corresponding "typical" luminosity.

Comment: Yeh, I understand if you times by $L$ then integrate the LF with respect to $L$ you get total luminosity, and then integrating the LF with respect to $L$ you get the number density. Divide one by the other to get the average. But I come out with some very problematic Gamma functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Total Luminosity with $\alpha=-1$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
L_{tot}&=\int_0^{\infty}L \Phi_0 \frac{L^*}{L}e^{-\frac{L}{L^*}}\frac{dL}{L^*}\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}\Phi_0 e^{-\frac{L}{L^*}}dL
\end{aligned}
$$
Now put $L'=L/L^*$ and you get:
$$
L_{tot}=\Phi_0L^* \int_0^{\infty}e^{-L'}dL'=\Phi_0L^*
$$
Total number:
$$
\begin{aligned}
N_{tot}&=\int_0^{\infty} \Phi_0 \frac{L^*}{L}e^{-\frac{L}{L^*}}\frac{dL}{L^*}\\
&=\int_0^{\infty} \Phi_0 \frac{1}{L}e^{-\frac{L}{L^*}}dL
\end{aligned}
$$
which diverges at the lower limit.

Observe with $\alpha=-1$ we have no gamma functions.

Also IIRC with $\alpha \in (-1,0)$ when computing $L_{tot}/N_{tot}$ the gamma functions cancel leaving $(1+\alpha)L^*$

Comment: Not sure your maths is correct there as you get a $L_{\star}$ to disappear in your final expression for $N_{tot}$.

Comment: Thinking it was just a typo.

Comment: Hi Conrad, could you explain or derive the last sentence where you state that the Gamma functions cancel...could you show me how this is done exactly...

Comment: You end up with something like $L_{tot}/N_{tot}=L^* \times \frac{\Gamma(\alpha+2)}{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}$ but $\Gamma(\alpha+2)=(\alpha+1)\Gamma(\alpha+1)$. Sorry I can't be more precise the derivation is at home and I'm not at present.

Comment: When you get back to your derivation at home could you share it with me. Still not sure how it shows that the average luminosity is $L_{\star}$ tho...

Comment: It doesn't, what you have is it typically is $L^*$ as per my first comment on the original question.

Comment: Just a quick question, on the third line how did you get the definite integral to be 1? Could you show those steps for me?

Comment: $\int_0^{\infty}\exp(-x)dx=\left[-\exp(-x) \right]_0^{\infty}=-\exp(-\infty)+\exp(-0)=0+1=1$

Comment: Of course, yes. Simple.